# Countdown installation on wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, countdown

I tried to install a basic countdown on a wordpress website ([View Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdownBasics.html)), but nothing happens.

The WordPress theme I'm using is "HTML5Blank". I enqueue the JavaScript files like this:

```
wp_register_script('jquery.plugin.min.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.plugin.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Custom scripts
wp_enqueue_script('jquery.plugin.min.js'); // Enqueue it!

wp_register_script('jquery.countdown.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.countdown.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Custom scripts
wp_enqueue_script('jquery.countdown.js'); // Enqueue it!
```

**index.php hosts the div:**

```
<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
```

**Initialized in header.php:**

```
<script>
    (function ($) {
        var austDay = new Date();
        austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
            until: austDay
        });
        $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: Yes, no error in the console...

Comment: can you share your url so we can look into?
with nothing happens I assume you mean like there's no output?

Comment: have to added `.countdown` script  after the `jquery.countdown.js`?

Comment: Yes here is the url : [link] (http://linstantdapres.fr/)
I try to implement the countdown just after the slider.

Comment: @RaunakGupta I don't understand your explanation. Could you explicit more ? Thx

Comment: @Foub: you have added all files in correct order. there is no issue with including the script.

Comment: @RaunakGupta So any idea why the countdown doesn't lauch on the website ?

Comment: Try by moving the Initialization script to `footer.php` after `wp_footer`.

Comment: @RaunakGupta It works. Thank you so much. I don't understand why it doesn't work on the header, but anyway, the countdown appears ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not populating because the `#defaultCountdown` element was not in the DOM/loaded but as you moved the script after the `<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>` So the JQuery got the element and worked.

Initialization script in `footer.php` after `wp_footer`.

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<script>
    (function ($) {
        var austDay = new Date();
        austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
            until: austDay
        });
        $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```